# Polymer dom-repeat not render children properly

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've searched now for quite a while and could find more less similar topics but no solution for my problem. I have an polymer element which is used recursive to render a tree with dom-repeat. The problem is that the elements are not rendered properly inside the dom-repeat when the observer triggers. In my example you can see that in the first 2 menu-test items the dom is rendered properly and the ul.list node is found. After the render() function of the dom-repeat element you can see that the element is not found anymore and the shady or light dom is not rendered.

Can someone help me out here?

Here is a jsbin example which demonstrates the problem: https://jsbin.com/zisakizeca/edit

```
<dom-module id="menu-test">
    <template>
        <content id="menu"></content>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{hasItems}}">
            items:
            <ul class="list">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" filter="filterItems" observe="changed">
                    <li>
                        <label>[[getLabel(item)]]: [[item.changed]]</label>
                        <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.children]]">
                            <menu-test items="[[item.children]]"></menu-test>
                        </template>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'menu-test',

            properties: {
                items: {
                    type: Array
                },
                hasItems: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    computed: 'itemsAreSet(items)'
                }
            },

            attached() {
                // Should find ul.list every time
                console.log(this.$$('.list'));
            },

            itemsAreSet(items) {
                return !!items;
            },

            getLabel(item) {
                return item.label || item;
            },

            filterItems(item) {
                return !item.changed;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Looks similar to https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3863#issuecomment-258512802

Comment: @tony19 No this is a different problem. I found out that it call the attached function differently when re calling the render function. Normal: create element -> bind data -> render -> attach. With dom-repeat.render() it is: create -> bind data -> attach -> render.  Therefore the elements are not there yet. Thats my current assumption